# Difference in calling structure variables

Tags: c

What is the difference between `->` and `.` while calling variables in a structure?I have seen both of them used in various scenarios but couldn't identify the difference between them.

Comment: One is used when you have a *pointer* to a structure. The other is when you have an *instance* of a structure. Please [find a good book to read about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `->` means you have a variable that points to a piece of memory containing the struct. To access its members, you must dereference the pointer and then add the offset to the member. the `->` does that for you.
- the `.` means your variable *is* the structure and you only need to add the offset to the member.

As user Eliot B points out, if you have a pointer `s` to a struct, then accessing the member `elem` can be done in two ways: `s->elem` or `(*s).elem`.

With `(*s)` you have an expression that "is" the struct and you now use the dot-operator to access `elem`.

Answer (score 1):

`s->elem` is equal to `(*s).elem`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

Answer (score 1):

The difference is about the structure's defined instance. '->' and '.' operators is always about the left operand.

If left operand is a pointer, then you use '->', else you use '.'.

For example.

```
struct Foo bar1;
struct Foo* bar2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
bar1.variable = "text";
bar2->variable = "text";
```

Answer (score 1):

`x->y` (`->` is the *pointer to member operator*) is equivalent to `(*x).y`. Because of operator precedence, you can't write `*x.y` as that would be evaluated as `*(x.y)`.

The former is easier to type and is a lot clearer. It's used when `x` is a pointer to a structure containing the member `y`.